# DisplayFor showing on different line to LabelFor MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I created an Edit page in MVC and decided I did not want the ID to be editable, but I do want it to look like the rest, just greyed out preferably.

Here is my property:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EvpId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">                                
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EvpId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EvpId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

After doing some reading everyone seems to suggest using the `@Html.DisplayFor` which makes sense, even though it does not look like the rest.

However when swapping the `EditorFor` for the `DisplayFor` I notice that the label is not on the same line:

[image]

What is the simple way of having this on the same line as the corresponding label, I am using the standard out of the box bootstrap CSS.

**View Source** on page:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="EvpId">Id</label>           
    <div class="col-md-10">                                
        2
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="EvpId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the generated html please?

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny I've added the html as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Jasen's answer I was able to achieve what I wanted by altering the width of the `<span>` however this seemed abit messy:

```
<span class="form-control" style="width:280px;">@Model.EvpId</span>
```

The ultimate answer to my question was this as it is what I originally was looking for:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EvpId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Glad you found an answer - fyi there is a "form-control-static" css class that is intended for static content in place of a form control

Comment: Here's a link [`form-control-static`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls-static).

Answer (score 8):

I have had the same issue.
Jasen answer did not help, because `span` does not put an element into  the same horizontal line with label, but his later comment with the link to bootstrap doc solved the problem, we should use `p` tag instead of `span`.

So my final solution was:

```
<p class="form-control-static">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Contractor.Name) </p>
```

Thanks to Jasen!

Answer (score 3):

When you use `@Html.DisplayFor()` the helper is selecting markup based on the type. Here it chose to output a bare string and this breaks the Bootstrap [`form-horizontal`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) styling.

```
<div class="col-md-10">                                
    2 <!-- no surrounding tags for EvpId value -->
    ...
</div>
```

The easiest thing to do is just use plain html to insert your own tags

```
<div class="col-md-10">                                
    <span class="form-control-static">@Model.EvpId</span>
    ...
</div>
```

If you do this a lot or you have much more markup you can create a custom helper extension. This is a very simple example:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static HtmlString IdSpan(this HtmlHelper helper, string id)
    {
        return new HtmlString(String.Format("<span class=\"form-control\">{0}</span>", id));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div class="col-md-10">                                
    @Html.Idspan(Model.EvpId)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EvpId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Comment: This seems solution puts the ID back in the same styled text box, but un-editable, however the width takes up the whole page?

Comment: The width would depend on the container's grid class `col-md-10`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping in a P tag or SPAN I just put the class directly into the exiting DIV, and that worked too.

```
<div class="col-md-10 form-control-static">                                  
    ...
</div>
```